# spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin What is the extension tags used for

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I have a question that I can not find information in the spring clound documentation.

What is the **`<extensions>true</extensions>`** tag used in the spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin

Example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <baseClassForTests>com.example.MvcTest</baseClassForTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns on all the goals for you. Otherwise you would have to provide all of them manually via the `goals` section.